# Django Queryset GET (1 result) checking MAX value of one filed

Tags: django, django-queryset

Maybe the solution is to do it with Filter and then loop. But let's see if you guys can tell me a way to do it with GET

I have this query with GET as I need to be sure I get only one result

```
result = OtherModel.objects.get(months_from_the_avail__lte=self.obj.months_from_avail)
```

Months_from_avail is an Integer value.

**Example**

```
months_from_the_avail = 22
```

In the other model there's 3 lines.

```
A) months_from_the_avail = 0  
B) months_from_the_avail = 7
C) months_from_the_avail = 13
```

So, when I query it returns all of them as all are less than equal the value 22 but I need to get the 13 as is the last range.

```
range 1 = 0-6
range 2 = 7-12
range 3 = 13 ++
```

Is there any way that I haven't thought to do it? Or should I change it to filter() and then loop on the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the [first()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#first) section from the query order_by `months_from_the_avail`
Remember that django query are lazy, it won't execute until the query if finished calling so you can still use filter:

```
result = OtherModel.objects.filter(months_from_the_avail__lte=self.obj.months_from_avail).order_by('-months_from_the_avail').first()

#order by descending get first object which is the largest, return None if query set empty
```

another suggestion from Abdul which i think it's faster and better is using [latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#latest)

```
OtherModel.objects.latest('-months_from_the_avail')
```

Comment: You can also use `latest` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#latest), also there is `earliest` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#earliest)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thank for the suggestion but i don't think it apply in this as im using order_by to do ordering by a field, not an id field

Comment: You can pass a field name to `latest` though? It will do the ordering using that field name and give you the needed object. It is a shortcut compared to `order_by(...).last()` or `order_by(...).first()`

Comment: oh that pretty cool i didn't know about this yet, is this api new?

Comment: No it has been there since a long time :)

Comment: Not sure if it works in my example. The creation of the OtherModel objects is not in order so I don't know if the latest is the one I want. (latest it referes to greater id?) I think that ordering and getting the first result is more ¿secure? in my case

Comment: Yes you're right. It work in my case too: The negative sign in '-expire_date' means to sort expire_date in descending order. Since latest() gets the last result, the Entry with the earliest expire_date is selected.  Thank you!